# strapi installtion on windows stuck on installing dependencies

Tags: strapi

hi im new in strapi and i want to install it
but the problem is that installtion stuck on code bellow

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
? Choose your installation type Quickstart (recommended)
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at G:\websites\practice\strapi\back-end.
Creating files.
| Installing dependencies: [5/5] Building fresh packages...
```

in fact it stuck on this line for hours i googled this issue some solutions like updating npm and node to latest stable versions and etc
but no one work for me

***Editedt***
my issue solved by downgrading node version from 16 to 14 and npm from 8 to 6. in the process of installtion i faced with some errors that solved usng yarn instead of npm

Comment: What did your install command look like?

Comment: i used npx create-strapi-app my-projext --quickstart by the way by downgrading my node js to version 14 and npm to 6 finally i installed it.now i realize that wordpress is also be able to be an headless cms and ofcourse that is so much bettrt than strapi. this is my personal opinion